# Values for which Improper Integrals Converge

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I want to determine the values of $a$ and $b$ for which the following integrals converge:

(i) $$\int \limits _0 ^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+xb}dx$$

(ii) $$\int \limits _0^1 x^a(1-x^2)^b dx$$

My thought process thus far is as follows:

For (i), I thought about using the Comparison Test and the fact that $\int _1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}dx$ diverges if $p \le 1$ and converges if $p > 1$. Thus, I split the integral in (i) into 2:

$$\int \limits _0 ^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+xb}dx = \int \limits _0 ^1 \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+xb}dx + \int \limits _1 ^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+xb}dx$$ If I can find that both parts converge, the improper integral should converge. 
For the second part of the integral, note that

$$\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+xb} \le \frac{x^{a-1}}{x} = x^{a-2}, \quad \forall x\in (1,\infty)$$ when $b \ge 1$. Moreover, $$\int \limits _1 ^{\infty} x^{a-2} dx$$ converges when $a < 1$. Then, by the Comparison Test, does the second part of the integral converge when $a < 1$ and $b \ge 1$? Are these limits for $a$ and $b$ exhaustive? Also, does the first part of the integral converge? How would I check that? Do I use integration by parts?

For (ii), if both $a \ge 0 $ and $b \ge 0$, the integral converges, as the function is either a constant or a polynomial. From examination, I believe that the degree of the product has to be greater than -1; that is, $a+ 2b > -1$, as I think $\int \limits _0 ^1 x^p dx $ converges if $ p > -1$ and diverges if $p \le -1$, but I'm not sure how to prove that rigorously.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: HINT: I'll give you the values of the integrals, if it doesn't inspire you enough I come back in some time:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{a-1}}{b x+1} \, dx &=\pi  b^{-a} \csc (\pi  a) \\
\int_0^{\infty } x^a \left(1-x^2\right)^b \, dx &=-\frac{\pi  e^{\frac{i \pi  a}{2}} b \left(-1+e^{2 i \pi  b}\right) \Gamma (b)}{\left(1+e^{i \pi  a}\right) \left(1+e^{i \pi  (a+2 b)}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{a+3}{2}+b\right)}Z@
\end{align}

Also, are $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $Z@$ is a typo.